# How do I create a RAM disk using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ramdisk

I would like to create a RAM disk programmatically using Node.js, no matter what the underlying OS is (OS X, Linux and Windows should be supported).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Of course I can run a command as a child process, but I would need to write this code individually for each OS. For obvious reasons I'd like to avoid this.

Is there a better approach (even a module that does it would be fine)?

Comment: You are asking about the *bes*t way to achieve this, I would ask you if you know *any* way to achieve this using Node.JS exclusively.

Comment: As far as I know Windows doesn't even have RAM disk support built in -or am I wrong?

Comment: @randunel: I guess it's possible via a module written in C, but I did not find any. I hoped that anybody out there has already written something like that ...

Comment: @t.dubrownik: There used to be a tool called ramdisk.exe / a driver called ramdisk.sys, but as I have just seen it is gone in Windows 7+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a low level and uncommon operation like this, there is no standartized way to generate a RAM disk, it is platform dependent and hence there is no functionality of this in NodeJS and there won't be likely, you have to write an extension. In Windows, it will call ramdisk.exe (not so familiar with it) and on Linux it is availalbe under `/dev/shm` , which you can resize by mount options later. So, the best way is to find the best external program for Windows versions, and in Linux just mount and use the `/dev/shm` like a normal folder.

[More Info on /dev/shm](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html)