# require a module from memory instead of from disk - is this possible?

Tags: node.js, module, require

I'd like to `require` a Node.js module from memory, e.g. because it is generated at runtime or received from a network stream.

Is this possible at all?

How could you resolve this issue (without writing to disk and loading from there, of course)?

Basically, something such as:

```
var code = 'module.exports = { foo: "bar" };';
var obj = require(code);
console.log(obj.foo); // => bar
```

The only approach I can currently think of is using the `eval` function, such as:

```
var myModule = {};
eval(
  '(function (module) {' +
  '  var local = 5;' +
  '  module.exports = {' +
  '    foo: \'bar\'' +
  '  };' +
  '  module.exports.baz = \'baz\';' +
  '})(myModule)');
```

After evaluating, `myModule.exports` contains the exported object:

```
{
  foo: 'bar',
  baz: 'baz'
}
```

and anything that should be local inside the module stays local.

Hence, you could create a function `require2`, such as:

```
var require2 = function (code) {
  var temp = {};
  eval('(function (module) {' + code + '})(temp);');
  return temp.exports;
};
```

Anyway, I am interested in better ideas ... :-)

PS: Being able to require from a stream would be awesome :-)

Comment: The only sure way is to copy your module(s) to a [RAM Disk](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2008904)

Comment: Which, in turn, I can not create from Node.js in an easy way, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342024/how-do-i-create-a-ram-disk-using-node-js

Comment: Have you considered doing something like saving the generated module as a temp file, clearing it and reloading as needed?

Comment: Yes. This is possible, of course, but not very elegant as the file is not actually *needed*. Hence, if it could work without, I'd prefer it that way.

Comment: Have you considered the security implications of this? Where are the modules coming from?

Comment: Yes, I have. They are from a trusted source (a certificate-secured, trusted https connection), and they are checked using an HMAC. In the end, this is not more or less secure than loading from the local file system.

Comment: What are you gonna achieve with this?

Comment: Download modules on demand over the web using an ssl connection, verify their integrity using HMAC, and run them locally without the need to save them to disk.

Comment: Maybe that the only way to get a module from a stream, could be write C++ module that provides that feature...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a better idea I now went with the approach I had already described in my question with a few tweaks, but the general idea is to do:

```
var require2 = function (code) {
  var temp = {};
  eval('(function (module) {' + code + '})(temp);');
  return temp.exports;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581830/load-node-js-module-from-string-in-memory)

However, you can find a more complete implementation in the [require-from-string](https://github.com/floatdrop/require-from-string) package in Github.

The TL;DR is that you use the [Modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/modules.html) package in node.js to _compile the code from a string.