# Node.js API to construct a module programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Is there an API in Node.js, perhaps in user-land, that allows you to construct a CommonJS module programmatically, with or without using eval?

I would like my command line app to take the source code of a module as stdin and (re)construct the module in my program.

It would/could be used like:

```
cat foo.js | mynodeprogram
```

Comment: Where would `require()` load from?

Comment: Construct the source code you want, write the code to a temp file and then use `require()` on it to load it.

Comment: Isn't that nodejs in repl mode.

Comment: Probably the [`vm` module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/vm.html) – [`vm.runInNewContext()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_options).

Comment: @jfriend00 that's cheating :) is there a way without writing a temp file?

Comment: @SLaks require would come from node, in this case "mynodeprogram"

Comment: But how would it resolve paths?

Comment: it would use the current working directory to resolve paths

Comment: If you want to do it from memory, then you can just look at the source for `require()` and make your own function that uses code already in memory.  I don't really get what you're asking here.  You either use `require()` or use some other code loading scheme someone else has written or write your own using `eval()` or `new Function()`.  Those are pretty much the choices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17585470/1223975

Comment: I led to the demise of my own question