# Transpile a TypeScript file in memory

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I am looking for a CLI tool that can run a .ts file directly, without writing to a file. That would mean it transpiles in memory, and then somehow passes that data to the node.js executable. Does such an executable exist?

Comment: You can "compile" a node.js module from string data via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581830/load-node-js-module-from-string-in-memory

Comment: A shell pipe is what you describe

Comment: well node.js cannot compile a file from stdin. and also tsc (the typescript compiler) by default writes files out, not to stdout...so using shell pipes is not possible right off the bat, that's the point of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does such an executable exist?

Yes. Its called `ts-node`: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node

Answer (score 0):

As one commenter suggested, you can also do:

```
tsc --outfile /dev/stdout <file> | node
```

Comment: Please note that `--outfile` only works when `module` is set to `amd` or `system`