# Compile typescript code from STDIN rather than a file?

Tags: typescript

I'm building a (simple) command line tool that writes a temporary typescript file to disk and then performs type checking on the file via `tsc /tmp/foo/bar.ts --noEmit`.

I would like to send the code to `tsc` via STDIN instead of writing a file in `/tmp`.

**How can I run `tsc --noEmit` on code that is sent to `STDIN`?**

Comment: can you use [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#usage) (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752995/transpile-a-typescript-file-in-memory/44753766#44753766)?

Answer (score 1):

I tried [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#usage) as [vike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620603/vike) suggested. It worked fine but there's about a 1s startup cost to both `ts-node` and `tsc`. Creating all the files and compiling (`tsc --noEmit *.ts`) them all at once allowed me to pay startup cost that only once.

tldr;

I wanted to test the conformance of the 437 [ShExJ JSON tests](https://github.com/shexSpec/shexTest/tree/main/schemas) against [`@types/shexj`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/shexj/index.d.ts). I cloned the tests and constructed trivial ts files that tested the type.

```bash
for f in *.json; do time (
  (
    echo -en "import {Schema} from 'shexj'\nconst x:Schema = " &&
    cat $f
  ) |
  ../node_modules/.bin/ts-node
); done

real    0m1,336s
user    0m2,919s
sys     0m0,121s

real    0m1,233s
user    0m2,586s
sys     0m0,101s

real    0m1,374s
user    0m2,979s
sys     0m0,127s

real    0m1,257s
user    0m2,692s
sys     0m0,096s
…
```

It was taking > 1.2s/file. I bypassed ts-node and went straight to tsc:

```bash
for f in *.json; do time (
  (
    echo -en "import {Schema} from 'shexj'\nconst x:Schema = " &&
    cat $f
  ) > ../ts/$f.ts &&
  tsc --noEmit ../ts/$f.ts
); done

real    0m2,909s
user    0m7,356s
sys     0m0,171s

real    0m2,735s
user    0m7,077s
sys     0m0,182s

real    0m2,669s
user    0m6,822s
sys     0m0,173s

real    0m2,670s
user    0m6,952s
sys     0m0,123s
…
```

This was taking > 2.6s/file. As slow was invoking `ts-node` individually was, it was still faster than invoking `tsc` individually. (I wonder how they managed that.)

I wrote them all out at once:

```bash
time (
  for f in 0*.json; do (
    echo -en "import {Schema} from 'shexj'\nconst x:Schema = " &&
    cat $f
  ) > ../ts/$f.ts;
  done
)

real    0m0,021s
user    0m0,013s
sys     0m0,009s
```

and compiled them at once:

```bash
time tsc --noEmit ../ts/*.ts

real    0m3,198s
user    0m8,424s
sys     0m0,148s
```

Extrapolating, this saved me 9.5 mins of full CPU.

Answer (score 1):

So I came across this problem today and found a decent way to fix it!

You *do* need to do some simple post-processing of the output, and it doesn't really use `tsc` directly but rather `deno` as a way to compile (without running the code! don't worry!), but it's certainly usable and decently fast.

Simply pipe the output to `deno run -`, a Deno command that takes input from stdin and runs it directly.

The trick is to wrap it in a function to keep it from being ran. I've added `console.log((() => {` and `}).toString())` around the code I wish to transpile.

Here's what that looks like as Python code:

```py
import subprocess
import json

# Just pass your TypeScript code in one end, and get compiled JavaScript!
def transpile(code: str) -> str:

    # Add padding to code
    padded_code: str = "console.log((() => {" + code + "}).toString())"

    # Compile with `deno run -`
    out_code: str = subprocess.getoutput(f'echo "{json.dumps(padded_code)}" | deno run -')

    # Remove arrow function padding
    final_code: str = out_code[6:-2]

    return final_code
```

*Note: Turning type-checking on makes things a bit difficult for Deno's compiler, so it's very important to keep it off.*

Answer (score 1):

If type checking is not as important, you can also use swc with stdin: `swc -f filename.ts`.

Here's how to install & use:

```
pnpm install @swc/cli
echo "const a: number = 1" | swc -f index.ts
```

Output:

```
var a = 1;
```

Which can be piped to `node`:

```
$ echo "const a: number = 1; console.log(a)" | swc -f index.ts | node -
1
```