# Dynamic import of module from memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

I would like to allow a user of a webapp to upload some code-fragments in React (with JSX) that should be embedded dynamically in the code.

For instance the user writes a class with a render-Method that returns

```
<div>hello {this.props.name}</div>
```

Then the System should transpile this by Babel and maybe transform the result into something secure by Google Caja.
After that I want to be able to embed this in a way like that:

```
let code = theUsersCodeFragment;

import ForeignClass from code;

render() {
    return <MyContainer> 
                <ForeignClass name={"John"}>
           </MyContainer>
}
```

Is this possible (I know dynamic imports are just in stage 3)? 
I just found a way to load modules from memory by require: [Load node.js module from string in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581830/load-node-js-module-from-string-in-memory)

Comment: Why dont you simply concat the file as string to your code? Or import userCode from "user/"; where user simply returns the user uploaded file

Comment: The users code is in a database. I think one solution is, that every request with /user/ will get the transformed script from the database.
But isn't there another way to import something from memory instead of from a resource at serverside?